# FinalExporter not working in TensorFlow 2.1 on Google AI-Platform

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to upgrade my model to use AI-Platform 2.1 instead of 1.15, but I can't get the `FinalExporter` to work.

I followed the steps outlined in [ai-platform: No eval folder or export folder in outputs when running TensorFlow 2.1 training job using Estimators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337037/ai-platform-no-eval-folder-or-export-folder-in-outputs-when-running-tensorflow) and I've gotten it to a place where:

- The evaluation metrics are exported to the `eval` folder
- Both the `BestExporter` and `LatestExporter` are successfully exporting the model
- The `FinalExporter` does **not** export any model

The code I'm using for this is similar to:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
...

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(...)
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(...)

final_exporter = tf.estimator.FinalExporter("final", ...)
latest_exporter = tf.estimator.LatestExporter("latest", ...)
best_exporter = tf.estimator.BestExporter("best", ...)

eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
    input_fn=eval_input_fn,
    exporters=[latest_exporter, final_exporter, best_exporter],
    name="eval",
)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator=estimator, train_spec=train_spec, eval_spec=eval_spec)
```

and I'm using the following yaml config file

```yaml
trainingInput:
  runtimeVersion: "2.1"
  pythonVersion: "3.7"
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_v100
  evaluatorType: standard_gpu
  evaluatorCount: 1
```

The problem seems to be that the model is no longer being evaluated after the final training step. This can be seen in the tensorboard where the final eval is run after the last training metrics are exported in 1.15. This is no longer the case in 2.1.

[Tensorboard comparing the steps for which the last losses were recorded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COGfe.png)

#### Logs

The problem with the model no longer being evaluated after the final training step is supported by the logs:

> 2020-10-27 09:06:03.504 EDT
> master-replica-0
> "Saving checkpoints for 77872 into ...
>
> ...
>
> 2020-10-27 09:06:19.033 EDT
> evaluator-replica-0
> "Calling model_fn."
>
> ...
>
> 2020-10-27 09:06:20.093 EDT
> master-replica-0
> "Loss for final step: 50.796585."
>
> ...
>
> 2020-10-27 09:06:28.005 EDT service Tearing down training program.
>
> ...
>
> 2020-10-27 09:06:28.430 EDT evaluator-replica-0 "Terminated by service. If the job is supposed to continue running, it will be restarted on other VM shortly."

which indicates that the `evaluator-replica-0` is being shut down as soon training has finished, while in the middle of evaluating.

Is this a bug in TF/AI-Platform 2.1 or do I have to do something differently to ensure that the evaluator evaluates the model (and exports it) after the final training step?