# evaluation not done/ export no provided when training a TF model on AI Platform

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have TF a DNNRegressor to train Locally / Cloud in GCP (AI Platform).

If the training is done locally (through the `gcloud` command below), there will be checkpoints, eval folder and export folder.

```sh
gcloud ai-platform local train   \
  --module-name=babyweight.task   \
  --package-path=/home/jupyter/end-to-end-ml/examples/e2e-ml-model-ex02/app/babyweight   \
  --   \
  --nnsize 64 32   \
  --train-data-path=/home/jupyter/end-to-end-ml/examples/e2e-ml-model-ex02/preproc/train.csv*   \
  --eval-data-path=/home/jupyter/end-to-end-ml/examples/e2e-ml-model-ex02/preproc/eval.csv*
```

But, if the training is done in the cloud (through the `gcloud` command below), there will be only checkpoints. This is was not expected from my side. After checking the documentation, it is clear that the node `chief` does not run evaluation.

```sh
export BUCKET=$(gcloud info --format='value(config.project)')
export JOB_ID=appbabyweight_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training  $JOB_ID \
  --region=us-east1 \
  --module-name=babyweight.task \
  --package-path=/home/jupyter/end-to-end-ml/examples/e2e-ml-model-ex02/app/babyweight \
  --scale-tier=BASIC \
  --runtime-version=2.4 \
  --python-version=3.7 \
  --staging-bucket=gs://$BUCKET \
  -- \
  --nnsize 64 32 \
  --output-dir=gs://$BUCKET/$JOB_ID/output-dir \
  --train-data-path=gs://$BUCKET/babyweight/preproc/train.csv* \
  --eval-data-path=gs://$BUCKET/babyweight/preproc/eval.csv* \
  --train-records-count=10000 \
  --eval-steps=1000
```

To overcome this behavior, I defined `--use-chief-in-tf-config=false` as it can be seen below. Unfortunately, no eval folder and no export folder are provided after the training job is done.

```sh
export BUCKET=$(gcloud info --format='value(config.project)')
export JOB_ID=appbabyweight_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training  $JOB_ID \
  --region=us-east1 \
  --module-name=babyweight.task \
  --package-path=/home/jupyter/end-to-end-ml/examples/e2e-ml-model-ex02/app/babyweight \
  --use-chief-in-tf-config=false \
  --scale-tier=BASIC \
  --runtime-version=2.4 \
  --python-version=3.7 \
  --staging-bucket=gs://$BUCKET \
  -- \
  --nnsize 64 32 \
  --output-dir=gs://$BUCKET/$JOB_ID/output-dir \
  --train-data-path=gs://$BUCKET/babyweight/preproc/train.csv* \
  --eval-data-path=gs://$BUCKET/babyweight/preproc/eval.csv* \
  --train-records-count=10000 \
  --eval-steps=1000
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should check this related SO question:

[ai-platform: No eval folder or export folder in outputs when running TensorFlow 2.1 training job using Estimatorssearchlucky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337037/ai-platform-no-eval-folder-or-export-folder-in-outputs-when-running-tensorflow)

It is explained that Chief by default does not act as an evaluator.

In order to get evaluation data, you have to update your config yaml to explicitly allocate an evaluator.

https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/distributed-training-details#tf-config-format